# Finding and Saving Media Player Classic downloaded subtitles?

Tags: video, subtitles, media-player-classic

Recently I discovered this feature which enables users to download subs directly from the MPC program. However, I thought that by default it downloaded the file directly to the folder where the movie is stored at, but that's not true.

I tried to find on the whole system for the temporary folder which the subs are stored, but I had no success at all.

Does anybody know where are these downloaded subs stored at? Some sort of temporary folder/file over the HDD or just on the RAM? Can I, at least, (or is there an option to) export the currently downloaded subs of the movie to somewhere else?

Comment: According to this page you must choose where to save them.  http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/finding_and_adding_subtitles_through_media_player_classic.cfm

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thanks @Moab! But is there an option I can set to save them directly after downloading them to attach to the movie folder, or I have to save them manually every time I need?

Comment: This really needs to be a feature, doesn't appear to be an option at current.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is temporary saved, but you can save the subtitle you have downloaded 
through the File → Save Subtitle  command or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.